# Fastest way to Dynamic Query on 2 million in memory rows

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures

I have 2 million rows of data in memory and I want to apply dynamic groupby and dynamic where(Dynamic filter) clause. I need records in max 10 seconds. I have tried so for:

1. Dynamic Linq, it is working fine but returning result in more than 60 seconds and it is not acceptable.
2. I have used datatable and apply filter and compute function and it is returning data in 20-30 seconds.

is there any other datastructure, library or some approach/algo that I can use to speed up this query to get result in 10 seconds or less with dynamic groupby and dynamic filter facility.

My data has the following fields

```
"Company"
"City"
"SellPrice"
"BuyPrice"
```

I am grouping dynamically on `Company` and `City` fields and performing *Aggregate* function on `price` fields

and calling it as:

```
 public DataTable GroupBy(string[] gorupByColumns, string aggregateColumn, DataTable table, string columnName, string Formula, string whereClause)
    {
        bool IsNoGroupIng = false;
        DataTable d;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(whereClause))
        {
            table.DefaultView.RowFilter = whereClause;
            d = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
            table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "";
            table = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
        }
        else
        {
            d = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
        }
        DataView dv = new DataView(d);
        DataTable dtGroup = null;
        if (gorupByColumns.Length ==1 && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gorupByColumns[0]))
        {
            dtGroup = dv.ToTable();
            IsNoGroupIng = true;
        }
        else
        {
            dtGroup = dv.ToTable(true, gorupByColumns);
        }
        if (columnName.ToLower() == "sum")
        {
            dtGroup.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(double));

        }
        else
        {
            dtGroup.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(double));

        }
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtGroup.Rows)
        {
            if (IsNoGroupIng)
            {
                dr[columnName] = d.Compute(Formula, "");
                break;
            }
            string operation = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < dtGroup.Columns.Count -1; i++)
            {
                if (i>0)
                {
                    operation += " AND ";
                }
                operation += dtGroup.Columns[i].ColumnName + " = '" + dr[i] + "'";
            }
            dr[columnName] = d.Compute(Formula, operation);
        }
        if (IsNoGroupIng && dtGroup.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            dTable.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(double));
            DataRow row = dTable.NewRow();
            row[columnName] = dtGroup.Rows[0][columnName];
            dTable.Rows.Add(row);
            return dTable;
        }
        return dtGroup;
    }
```

GroupBy(arr, "Price", dt,"MyCustomColumn","Sum(Price)", "Country IN ('Country1.Country2')");

Comment: There is.... Spark for .NET :) check [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/03/developing-apache-spark-applications-in-net-using-mobius.html) or [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt595756.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) link. Another approach would to use of Task Library of .NET and split your data into batches. Then you can proceess your batches in parallel through tasks. Good luck

Comment: 2 million isn't a lot of anything really. However for anyone to have a chance of answering this you need to add the relevant parts of your data structure, and what you're grouping on (and how). By not using Linq and the right application of loops i bet you blow the 10 second requirement out of the water

Comment: Check task manager memory while running query to see if issue is memory size.  If you are doing any joins try replacing with with WITH which is sometimes faster.  With datatable try : dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Col A") == "abc");

Comment: My data has the following fields "Company","City","SellPrice","BuyPrice". I am grouping dynamically on Company and City fields and performing aggregate function on price fields.

Comment: Can you update and give an example of your query, just so we are all on the same page

Comment: You can’t even show 2 million records on the screen. You need some paging mechanism. If the data comes from the database, handle it there. Either way, you need indexes if you want to make it fast. It really depends on your data structure.

Comment: Consider this: One bulk insert to a database management system, then each query to the db would take smaller time. Also, remember indexing in the db.